# HTTP Request From Server to Website Received 511 Network Authentication Required Error

Tags: networking, authentication

I've setup a web application on Linode server that will ping some sites occasionally. It is working fine without any problem. But there is only one site which failed to access. It is a public eCommerce site and I've tried the most basic Linux `ping`, the simple PHP `file_get_contents` and the more robust PHP `GuzzleHttp` and they all return with `511 Network Authentication Required` error. It only failed on my Linode server, but able to access the site using the same cmd/code from my local computer.

I've tried to Googled around. Some suggested that it is due to network restriction, similar to airport or cafe Wifi that requires authentication to access. But my server is on Linode and should already have access to public websites. It is also able to access other sites.

Some other suggested that it is due to the target website requires login authentication. But it is just a public eCommerce site and I don't see any login request when I browse the site using my browser.

I wonder what is wrong and how to fix this. There isn't a lot of discussion about 511 error available online.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/511
"This status is not generated by origin servers, but by intercepting proxies that control access to the network."

Does your linode have a proxy configured or is it supposed to connect to the server directly? (There's networks that only allow outgoing traffic through proxies...)

Have you already tried to reach out to the linode support? Guess they know their own network (restrictions) the best.